# Why do I not get type errors in my Node Application although I specify the type of the function argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I have a the following class

```
class Order {
    constructor(id){
       this.id=id;
    }
}
```

and a function that takes an order as an argument:

```
/** 
 * @param {Order} order
*/
async function doSomething(order){
  // the problem is now that I can type something like that
   console.log(order.ids) // the key ids does not exist on the class Order but still no error
}
```

I wonder what I have to do such that keys which do not exist on a class are marked as errors.
I am using Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a language or tool that does type checking. Just putting `{Order}` in a comment doesn't do anything. You'd have to have some tool that understands that JSDoc format and checks your code. JavaScript itself A) Completely ignores comments, and B) Doesn't provide any parse/compile-time type checking. One such tool is [typelint](https://github.com/yarax/eslint-plugin-typelint), an ESLint plug-in. (Not an endorsement, I've never used it.) [jantimon points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64750657/157247) that VSCode itself can do it for you (which seems *really* cool) with your existing JSDoc type annotations.

If you want type safety, a very popular choice right now is to use [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org). TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to JavaScript. Here's that code in TypeScript:¹

```typescript
class Order {
    id: number;
    constructor(id: number) {
       this.id = id;
    }
}
// ...elsewhere...
async function doSomething(order: Order) {
   console.log(order.ids);
}
```

There are other options, though, such as [Flow](https://flow.org/en/).

---

¹ The class part can also be written like this, which is functionally identical to the version above:

```typescript
class Order {
    constructor(public id: number) {
    }
}
```

Putting `public` in front of the constructor argument tells TypeScript that it should create a public property with the same name as the parameter and automatically generate code in the constructor to assign the parameter's value to the property.

Comment: So, I could use only typescript also in my Node Application? I did not know that. If that is possible, I would instantly switch to typescript only! I will look it up!

Comment: @CNIS - Yes, you can use TypeScript anywhere you can use JavaScript. :-) You just need a compilation stage. There's even [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) which lets you run TypeScript directly in Node.js via JIT compilation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to typecheck `.js` files with typescript you need to add `// @ts-check` to your code.

E.g.:

```
// @ts-check

class Order {
    constructor(id){
       this.id=id;
    }
}

/** 
 * @param {Order} order
*/
async function doSomething(order){
   console.log(order.ids) // the key ids does not exist on the class Order but still no error
}
```

Now Visual Studio Code will show you an error during development:

[image: TSCheck VsCode]

You can also use the typescript cli to test your code programmatically:

```
npx typescript --noEmit --allowJs index.js

  npx: installed 1 in 1.344s
  index.js:13:22 - error TS2339: Property 'ids' does not exist on type 'Order'.

  13    console.log(order.ids) 
                          ~~~


  Found 1 error.
```

See for details: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html

Comment: That's a **really** cool middle ground between not using type checking and actually switching to TypeScript!

Comment: Yes, I also like this approach. I tried using typescript with node but I did not find any tutorial showing how to switch from JS to TS in the whole project (routes). So, I think I will use this approach.

Comment: @CNIS - FWIW, I think this answer is a more direct answer to the question you actually asked than mine is, if you feel like switching the "accepted" mark here. I think mine's useful too, but this is more directly how to get from where you are to what you wanted VSCode to do. It's entirely up to you whether to leave it or switch it, of course.

Comment: thank you so much @T.J.Crowder - it means a lot to me that this comes from you! :)